# Eliminar llaves foráneas cuando elimine la primaria en SQL

Tags: sql

Quiero saber como puedo eliminar los campos de llave foránea cuando elimine su llave primaria en dos tablas relacionadas de SQL.

Tengo una tabla llamada Devoluciones con el campo Iddev que es la llave primaria, y en la tabla DevolucionProducto tengo el mismo campo Iddev como llave foranea, lo que quiero saber es si al borrar una fila de la tabla Devolucion, se borran las filas de la tabla DevolucionProducto.

Comment: Investiga sobre el modo de borrado en cascada

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, ya lo pude entender.